# Formatting strings in java

Tags: java, string

I am reading the serial buffer with readLine() method. The string returned by readLine() is in the format "str1 : str2". In a while loop when I use readLine() number of times for a response of serial port command I get weird output like this :

```
String1 : string1
SString11 : String2
StringString2 : String23 
String4 : String5
```

But I need the output formatted as below

```
String1       : string1
SString11     : String2
StringString2 : String23 
String4       : String5
```

I used the split method on string and get the two strings separated with delimiter as ':'. But now I need to append the String1 with spaces to align all the colons.

I am sorry If my problem explanation is weird. But If anybody understood the problem can you please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [System.out.printf](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: I used String.format() and It worked. But another problem is there. Problem is I am putting the output string in a JTextArea instance. I have choosen the font as Arial. When print like this String.format("%-30s:%30s",temp[0],temp[1]);
It prints like
Image Name                     :           Basic Linux firmware 
Version                        :                       2.1.1.17 
In the above two lines "I" in word Image and "V" in word Version has different width on text area. So even though i m using 30 character string the colons are not aligning. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: take a look at java.awt.FontMetrics (maybe... been a long time since I cared about the width of a text field/area :-)

Comment: You need to use a font such as Courier, this is referred to as a 'monospaced' font meaning that all the characters have equal width. This would of course mean that if you characters align in the string the would align on ouput as well.

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use *System.out.format()*. This lets you use C *printf* style format specifiers. An example:

```
System.out.format("%-5s:%10s\n", "Name", "Nemo");
System.out.format("%-5s:%10d\n", "Age", 120);
```

This will output:

```
Name :      Nemo
Age  :       120
```

Also see documentation for the [Formatter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class to learn more about the format string syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Can I get the formated output stored in a string instead of sending to System.out stream? Is there any API?

Comment: You can use String.format() the same way as System.out.format() to get the result as a String.

Comment: +1 for linking to java.util.Formatter which is possibly more useful for the question poster than System.out's format() or printf() as it can format to arbitrary streams and it's not clear in the post what the destination of the output is.

Comment: @Surjya Narayana Padhi To get the formatted output stored in a string, use String.format().

Comment: I used String.format() and It worked. But another problem is there. Problem is I am putting the output string in a JTextArea instance. I have choosen the font as Arial. When print like this String.format("%-30s:%30s",temp[0],temp[1]); It prints like Image Name : Basic Linux firmware Version : 2.1.1.17 In the above two lines "I" in word Image and "V" in word Version has different width on text area. So even though i m using 30 character string the colons are not aligning. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Used a fixed width font like Courier New, Lucida Console, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Consolas, etc

Answer (score 4):

System.out.format("%30s : %s", str1, str2);

Will print the first string with a fixed width of 30 characters.

Comment: I like the right justification of the first parameter here!