# C++ setw() for Java

Tags: java, c++

Is there a function in Java like `setw(int)` in C++?
It is needed in matrix output.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++ but maybe this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899138/formatting-strings-in-java

Comment: That seems to be a utility function deeply specific to C++'s string I/O via streams. Java's I/O methods are just as powerful, but somewhat different, therefore there may be no direct equivalent to this method. If you just need to format output nicely, then `String.format()` and `String.printf()` would be enough for you. otherwise, please elaborate.

Comment: Most peoples here is not perfect in both C++ and Java, elaborate why and where you use `setw(int)` in C++, then we will try to provide similar thing in java.

Answer (score 1):

Java's `java.util.Formatter` class does not provide dynamic specification of field width a la `setw()` or `printf`'s dynamic width specifier `*` (as in `%*s`, which reads an argument off the list to get the width).

However, you could accomplish the same thing by making two passes, one to build the format string with the widths interpolated, and then using the format string to write the output.