# Any ideas on getting these columns to line up (Java)?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm practicing writing for loops in Java. This is what I have so far:

```
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
System.out.println ("Num  "+"Square  "+"Num  "+"Square  "+"Num  "+"Square  "+"Num  "+"Square  ");
    for (int x = 1; x<=20; x++) {
                a = x * 1;
                b = 20+a;
                c = 40+a;
                d = 60+a;
               for (int y = 1; y <= 1; y++) {
System.out.println (a + "     " + (a * a) + "      " + b + "   " + (b * b) + "      " + c +
             "     " + (c * c) + "      " + d + "     " + (d * d));
              }

         }
```

I don't want to change the code at all (meaning I don't want to add anything more complicated than I already have), but I'd like the columns to line up. When the numbers start increasing in digits, obviously the spacing gets messed up. Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: To answer your questions, I'm pretty new to this and haven't taught myself much more than this. I'm more than sure there are way better ways to do this, but I'm just practicing my for loops. Anywho, thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you want to control the formatting of the output ?

Comment: Why not just spit out a CSV or an HTML table to display in, eg, Excel or a browser? It's 2013. You don't have to worry about printing text directly to a dot matrix printer, anymore.

Comment: You might want to start by getting your *code* to line up... it's very difficult to read your code example.

Comment: You need to have done a "pre" loop that will provide you with information about the maximum width of each column.  You would then use this information to actually display the data.  So, no, it can't be done (easily) without modifying your existing code and adding in another loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899138/formatting-strings-in-java)

Comment: the use of tabs could fix it to an extent + "\t"

Answer (score 1):

You can use tab(`\t`) to format it. A double tab will provide more space in your case.

```
// Changed Num to Number - Out of habit
System.out.println("Number\t\t" + "Square\t\t" + "Number\t\t" + "Square\t\t" + "Number\t\t" + "Square\t\t" + "Number\t\t" + "Square");

System.out.println(a + "\t\t" + (a * a) + "\t\t" + b + "\t\t" + (b * b) + "\t\t" + c + "\t\t" + (c * c) + "\t\t" + d + "\t\t" + (d * d));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String appendBlankSpace(int val){
String returnValue=Integer.toString(val);
int lengthTobeAppend=10-returnValue.length();
//Here you can use any number instead of 10.It is for space allocated for a column

for(int i=1;i<=lengthTobeAppend;i++){
returnValue= " " + returnValue;
}

return returnValue;
}
```

now you can use,

```
System.out.println (appendBlankSpace(a) + appendBlankSpace(a * a) +       appendBlankSpace(b) + appendBlankSpace(b * b) +  appendBlankSpace(c) + appendBlankSpace(c *     c) + appendBlankSpace(d) + appendBlankSpace(d * d));
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can store a,b,c,d values in array like inside loop

```
 for (int x = 1; x<=20; x++) {
                a = x * 1;
                b = 20+a;
                c = 40+a;
                d = 60+a;
               int [] array = {a,b,c,d}

               //using enhanced for loop
               for(int ele : array){
                     System.out.println(ele +"\t\t"+ ele*ele)
                 } 
}
```

output will appear like :

2  4

3  9

4  16

Answer (score 0):

Use printf.

```
public class Squarely {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 20; ++x) {
            int a = x, b = 20+x, c = 40+a, d = 60+a;
            System.out.printf("%6d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d%n",
                    a, a*a, b, b*b, c, c*c, d, d*d);
        }
    }
}
```